# Problems with Doctrine 2 CRUD generator and identifier which isn't called "id"

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

**Here is the situation:**
I'm kind of new to Symfony2 and liking all about it, but I'm having an issue with Doctrine's CRUD generator. I've generated entities with Doctrine starting from YAML files but can't generate their CRUD with the doctrine:generate:crud command line.

**The problem:**
For some reason I need to set an 'id' field and a getId() method, but it kind of ruins all the work I've done on class diagrams and relation schema…

**My question is:**
Is there a way to keep my field names as they are and get Doctrine to still generate my CRUDs?

A YAML example:

```
XXX\XXXBundle\Entity\Utilisateur:
 type: entity
 table: utilisateur
 id:
  pseudo:
   type: string
 fields:
  nom:
   type: string
```

I'm stuck with this… I've tried to change it for:

```
XXX\XXXBundle\Entity\Utilisateur:
 type: entity
 table: utilisateur
 fields:
  pseudo: # Le pseudo correspond au nom affiché pour identifier un utilisateur.
   type: string
   id: true
```

But it doesn't change any thing I always end up having this:

```
[RuntimeException]                                                                                      
The CRUD generator expects the entity object has a primary key field named "id" with a getId() method.
```

I'd be really grateful if anyone could help out a bit! Worst case scenario I'll have to modify all my entities to add a stupid ID field with an auto-generated integer…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

There is already a change request: 
https://github.com/sensio/SensioGeneratorBundle/issues/57

It is hardcoded in [DoctrineCrudGenerator.php](https://github.com/sensio/SensioGeneratorBundle/blob/master/Generator/DoctrineCrudGenerator.php#L69) on line 69 - 71:

```
if (!in_array('id', $metadata->identifier)) {
    throw new \RuntimeException('The CRUD generator expects the entity object has a primary key field named "id" with a getId() method.');
}
```